# R smoothing functions

Tags: r, smoothing

I have an R plot that looks like this:

[image]

The redline is the attempted smoothing with `lines(smooth.spline(x, y, spar=0.000001))`. Notice the insanely low spar value that STILL fails to include the spike near the end of the graph. Nevertheless, it is because of the number of points plotted: 107350. The 20 points near the end are unable to sway, although it is clearly noticeable that these are different than the rest.

What kind of R smoothing function could I use that encompasses these points?

Or if a smoother won't do it, how would I be able to "statistically" distinguish these points?

Comment: `changepoint` package? Despite the more noticeable high outliers on the right, you should maybe listen to your smoother which is telling your there's more mass below... You question seems more statistical than programming-related. You should probably move it to [stats.stackexchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Gregor No, it's not meant for "listening" to. I am actually GLAD to see outliers. I shall explain why. The data I am operating on is genomic cancer data. The x-axis represents the position in the DNA. The y-axis represents, in simplified terms, the number of mutations certainly found. That region at the end of the chromosome 14 DNA, although extremely small is extremely significant. That region is one's immunoglobulin genes, which are known for extremely high rates of mutation, due to the body's need to create diversity in antibody production.

Comment: @NerdLife Yeah sure. I shall upload the .RData file. Just go to [this](http://dropbox.com/s/h9tkh8x9u1dqy8z/clustering.RData) Dropbox link, download the file. When opening R, use `load(filepath)`. Use `ls()` to check for any variables. If it is a new session, the data set should be the only variable loaded. I am pretty sure it will be called `df.add`. The data plotted on the graph above are the second and fourth columns of the data frame, for clarification.

Comment: @NerdLife, I still want to see your answer, but here is something interesting I found. `supsmu(x,y, wt=weights, span=0.01)`. The weights vector is basically a vector that must be the length of the number of (x,y) points. The weights vector also can be used to weight certain points more than others. For example if I want to weight all points such that `y > 140`. `weights <- rep(1, length(y))`. Then, `weights[which(y) > 140] <- 2000`. This then produces a smoothed spike at the end. In conjunction with changepoint analysis, as indicated by @Gregor, this may well provide an efficient analysis.

Comment: Oh wow, it seems `loess(y~x)` - a much more widely employed statistical method also has such a parameter. In fact so does `smooth.spline(x, y)`, since it seems that `smooth.spline(x, y)` operates significantly faster than `loess(y~x)` on large datasets like these.